# pointers to an array only print the first character?

Tags: c

Just started learning c. I'm confused with the pointers and arrays.
This is my main function.

```
int next_statement(char *a, int n);
void consume_char(char c);
int var_lib_check(char type,char var);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char statement[MAX_LINE];
int statement_len;
char type[MAX_LINE];
char var[MAX_LINE];

/* Print the output header comment */
printf(OUTPUT_HEADER, argv[0]);

/* Loop through statements read on stdin */
while ((statement_len = next_statement(statement,MAX_LINE)) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n",statement);
    sscanf(statement,"%s %s",type,var);
    var_lib_check(*type,*var);
}
return 0;

int
var_lib_check(char type,char var){
char var_library[MAX_VARS][MAX_LINE];
char new_var[MAX_LINE];
int num_of_var;
int z;
num_of_var = 0;

printf("%s and %s",&type,&var);
if (strcmp(&type,DOUBLE_TYPE)==0||strcmp(&type,INT_TYPE)==0||
        strcmp(&type,RTRN_TYPE)==0){
    for (z= 0; z < num_of_var; z++){
        if (strcmp(var_library[z],&var) == 0){
                sprintf(new_var,"x%d",z);
                printf("%s %s",&type,new_var);
                return z;
        }
    }
    strcpy(var_library[num_of_var],&var);
    num_of_var += 1;
    sprintf(new_var,"%x%d",num_of_var);
    printf("%s %s",&type,new_var);
        }
return num_of_var;
}
```

This program reads the input and if it is either int  or double ... it would replace it to be for e.g. int x0.

Why does it only print the first letter of the type and variable when it runs the function when it should print the whole string?

```
int
next_statement(char *a, int n) {
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i < n && (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        if (c == CHAR_SEMI) {
            consume_char('\n');
            break;
        }
        a[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == CHAR_SEMI) {
        a[i] = '\0';
        return i; /* index when ; was read, so the length of saved. */
    }
    else if (i >= n) {
        printf("%s Line too long.\n", ERROR_PREFIX);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}



/* reads one char from stdin and errors if it is not what was
 * expected, thereby "consuming" the given char.
 */
void
consume_char(char c) {
    int x;
    if ((x=getchar()) != c) {
        printf("%s expected '%c' found '%c'.\n", ERROR_PREFIX, c, x);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return;
```

Comment: You should not pass the address of the variable to `printf()`.

Comment: @user3121023 I tried that and it still didn't change anything. Let me post the rest of my code.

Comment: @user3121023 sorry i can't post another question yet. I tried making new_var,var_library, and num_of_var static. But the output remained the same.

Comment: @user3121023 removing the num_of_var fixed it. But why though? Could you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are passing only the first `char` to `var_lib_check()`. You have to pass the array, so first fix this

```
var_lib_check(*type,*var);
```

make it

```
var_lib_check(type,var);
```

then fix the `var_lib_check()` function

```
int
var_lib_check(char *type, char *var)
{
    char var_library[MAX_VARS][MAX_LINE];
    char new_var[MAX_LINE];
    int num_of_var;
    int z;
    num_of_var = 0;

    printf("%s and %s", type, var); /* remove the & */
    if (strcmp(type, DOUBLE_TYPE) == 0 || strcmp(type, INT_TYPE) == 0 || \
            strcmp(type, RTRN_TYPE)==0)
    {
        for (z = 0 ; z < num_of_var ; z++)
        {
            if (strcmp(var_library[z], var) == 0)
            {
                sprintf(new_var, "x%d", z);
                printf("%s %s", type, new_var);
                return z;
            }
        }
        strcpy(var_library[num_of_var], var);
        num_of_var += 1;
        sprintf(new_var, "%x%d", num_of_var);
        printf("%s %s", type, new_var);
    }
    return num_of_var;
}
```

Most of the code invokes undefined behavior, because you pass the address to a `char` where a pointer to a string is expected.

A string consists of a sequence of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte, since you where passing the address to just one byte, the functions, namely `printf()` and `strcmp()` where reading past the value of the passed variable.

Comment: Thanks it fixed that part. But now the loop just replaces the strings in my var_library every time i put in a new input. When I input int hello; it prints out int hello\n int x0. and then i enter double blue; it prints out double blue\n double x0 when it should be x1. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to check for bugs in the code that gets the input, I would think that your strings were `free()`d or deallocated somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what it means when the strings are deallocated.

Comment: Maybe you declared the strings as arrays inside a function and returned the address, I suggest enabling compilation warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have the function definition as

```
int var_lib_check(char type,char var){
```

and you call it as

```
var_lib_check(*type,*var);
```

By doing this, you are only passing one character, and not the entire string to it.

You should change your function to

```
    int var_lib_check(char *type,char *var)
```

and call it as

```
    var_lib_check(type,var);
```

Now, you are passing the string to it, and you can work on it like a pointer.

Comment: Thanks it fixed that part. But now the loop just replaces the strings in my var_library every time i put in a new input. When I input int hello; it prints out int hello\n int x0. and then i enter double blue; it prints out double blue\n double x0 when it should be x1. How do I fix this?